# Unity 5: Rigidbody 2d sticking to ceiling while velocity is moving upwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am making a 2d game. My problem is that while playing, if the player holds jump and is under a BoxCollider2D, the player will not fall until they release jump.

My player GameObject consists of a sprite renderer, a dynamic rigidbody2d with gravity on and a boxcollider2d.

Here are my movement scripts:

1:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [Range(1, 10)]
    public float jumpVelocity;

    [Range(0,10)]
    public float speed;
    private bool jumpQueue = false;
    private bool boolin=false;
    void Update()
    {

        //Friggin fall, loser

        //Jumping
        ///*
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump")&& GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>                ().velocity.y==0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up *     jumpVelocity;
        }
        //*/
        //jumpQueue?
        /*
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpQueue = true;
        }*/
        //Right Movement
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1*speed,         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            boolin = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0,     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            boolin = false;
        }
        //Left Movement
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-1*speed,     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            boolin = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0,     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            boolin = false;
        }
        //No movement?
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0,     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            boolin = false;

        }

        //Time to handle animation, boios.
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        bool schwomp = false;
        bool schwift = false;
        if(rb.velocity.y>0)
        {
            schwomp = true;
        }
        if(rb.velocity.y<0)
        {
            schwift = true;
        }
        Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (boolin)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Boolin", 1);
            /*if (!anim.GetBool("expand"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("expand", true);
                anim.Play("running");
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Boolin", 0);
            /*
            if(anim.GetBool("expand"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("expand", false);
                anim.Play("Idle");
            }*/
        }
        if(schwomp)
        {
            //anim.SetInteger("Boolin", 2);
        }
        if(schwift)
        {
            //anim.SetInteger("Boolin", 3);
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

public class BetterJumper : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float fallMultiplier = 2.5f;
public float lowJumpMultiplier = 2f;

Rigidbody2D rb;

void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update()
{
    if(rb.velocity.y<0)
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up*Physics2D.gravity.y*(fallMultiplier-1)*Time.deltaTime;

    }
    else if(rb.velocity.y>0&&!Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please take a moment to format your code correctly.

Comment: You wrote what the problem is but did not provide what's the expected result....

Answer (score 3):

You're using `Input.GetKey()` which will poll the key every frame. This means more and more velocity is added the longer you hold jump. You've effectively built a jetpack rather than a jump force.

You should use `Input.GetKeyDown()` which will only fire once when a key is pressed down, then has to be released and pressed again in order to re-trigger. You then need to apply a single sufficiently strong vertical force using [`RigidBody.AddForce()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to make the character jump, rather than adding continuously to the velocity.

Additionally, you should really be caching the result of your `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` call when the script either wakes up or starts so that you're not calling it continuously; Each one of those calls takes processing time. Also, you should be using [`FixedUpdate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) for physics.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float thrust;
    public Rigidbody rb; // make the rigidbody variable available anywhere in the class

    void Start() {
        // cache the rigidbody component to the variable once on start
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        // use the variable reference from now on rather than making GetComponent calls
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * thrust);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll definitely try this when I can!

Answer (score 0):

Soviut's answer explains it quite nicely, but there's more that you need to know. You're directly manipulating the velocity, which overrides the effect of any forces, including gravity(despite the fact you're applying it manually). See the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

As demonstrated in Soviut's answer you should be applying forces and impulses, letting the physics engine determine the velocity. The only time you should set velocity directly is when you're building a simulation that intentionally has unrealistic physics(i.e. retro platformers). Even in that case, bear in mind that doing so creates a lot more work, because you'll need to factor in every little thing that creates movement. This means you're essentially re-inventing the physics engine.

Comment: Funny enough, I am trying to create a retro platformer, haha.

Comment: Wow how ironic. In any case you can achieve mostly the feel of a retro platformer if you limit the max velocity and don't go overboard with the forces you're applying. Good luck.

Comment: That's more of a workaround than a solution I can apply to other situations. However, I did use raycasting to determine if the player is grounded. That way, he now only jumps if he is on the ground. Thanks for the help!